# Difference between "He had taken a photo of me" and "He had been taking a photo of me"

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect

What is the difference in meaning between

> 1. He had taken a photo of me

and

> 2. He had been taking a photo of me.

What would be the passive voice of sentence 1?

> 3. I had my photo taken
> 4. A photo of me had been taken

Are these sentences grammatically correct? Do they make sense?

Comment: @deadrat The question should be migrated to ELL, it is now answerable. I took the liberty of changing **taken** in sentence 2  to **taking**, which I think is where the confusion arose  from. Both words have very  similar (if not identical) pronunciations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're probably right, but I hope chen wei chimes in to confirm. I'll delete my original comment, which is not misleading.

Comment: *I had been taken a photo of me* sounds wierd.

Comment: @user178049 agreed, I've changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

1. He was finished taking the photo and then something else happened.
2. He was in the process of taking the photo when something else happened.

For 3 and 4, yes and yes.